# Image donot show in rich response in actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Images donot show in basic card in rich response
I have provided the url of image but it didn't show an image

@Prisoner here is my code, please let me know if i am doing any mistake

```
app.intent('totalResponses', (conv, { Location }) => {
  // extract the num parameter as a local string variable

  if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
    conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
      'phone surface in the simulator.');
    return;
  }

  conv.ask('Hello World');

  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: `Hello`, // Note the two spaces before '\n' required for
                                 // a line break to be rendered in the card.
    title: 'Title: this is a title',
    image: new Image({
      url: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/13eEr2rYhSCEDKDwCLab29AqFMsKuOi4P/view',
      alt: 'Image alternate text',
    }),
  }));

});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is generating your basic card or the JSON that your code generates? It is difficult to help you if we don't have a minimal example of the problem.

Comment: I totally agree with what @Prisoner said, we can't really help you without your code. Otherwise it could be the JSON field named incorrectly or your image link is not https.

Comment: (And, to be clear - please update your original question to include the images.)

Comment: FYI and in case you don't know, if you are hosting your Action on Firebase's free tier you may not have connectivity to the image.

Comment: @Prisoner here is my code, please let me know if i am doing any mistake,

Comment: That url is pointing to an HTML page to view the image. You need to have a URL for the image only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the drive URL that you're using for the image. This URL is the one that is used to preview the image when you load it from Google Drive directly. It is an HTML page, rather than an image, so it won't display if you use it in a web page or in a card for the assistant.

To get the URL you need to use, you want to select the three dots at the top of that page and then "Embed item". You don't want to use the entire embed code - just the URL.

[image]

Comment: thank you @Prisone , the url which i found from iframe element (inside embed item) is also providing the html page and donot display the image in card, then i open the image in new tab (rightclick on image --> "open image in new tab") and then get the right url from there which works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps for a solution:

1. Get a shareable link URL from drive.
2. Open the terminal(UNIX) and execute this command. Can also use online unix based or local terminal

   ```
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php
   ```
3. Execute the following code

   ```
   echo <paste your link> | cut -d '/' -f 6
   ```
4. Copy the output which is a unique id.
5. Paste it after `&id=`:

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<paste the output unique key>
   ```